# Using CouchDB Replication via HTTPS

Tags: https, couchdb

I am able to replicate local and remote databases using the CouchDB replication feature. However, if I specify the source to be a secure URL (e.g. https://www.mysecurehost.com) CouchDB returns a 500 error. I am able to successfully replicate if I specify the target to be a secure URL). I am using CouchDB V1.0.2. Any help regarding this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure this makes a difference, but are you triggering the replication from within futon, using curl, or via some other approach?

Comment: We are triggering replication in two ways 1) via curl, and 2) via our application. We get an error in both cases.

Comment: Could be a bug. Thanks for adding that additional information, since it may help pinpoint the problem. Also, I added the https tag.

Comment: I have faced similar problem... try doing one time replication hope that should work fine... I have a problem with continuous replication and i fixed it by doing some config changes in my ngnix config..(ssl config).. if you are able to do one time replication then i can give you the config changes what i did

Answer (score 3):

According to [Cloudant support](http://support.cloudant.com/kb/faqs/im-having-trouble-replicating-inout-of-cloudant),

> CouchDB (including version 1.0.1) has
>   trouble with HTTPS replication. If you
>   can, try replicating with plain HTTP.
>   Otherwise you’ll have to wait until
>   CouchDB 1.1 is released (ETA early
>   2011).

They reference bug [COUCHDB-491 ("Support replication over SSL")](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/COUCHDB-491), which appears to be closed, but not actually fixed.

Update: [According to Cloudant](http://twitter.com/#!/cloudant/status/53829181179564032), the problem is still present if you're using a version of Erlang older than R14.

Comment: @JimZ See the update I just added. Please vote my answer up if you think it's a good one.

Answer (score 2):

The current CouchDB release 1.0.2 fixes these issues.

Comment: Thanks for responding. It looks like Jim is already on 1.0.2 and is still having problems.

Comment: In that case I'd appreciate a bug report with as much detail as possible so we can get this fixed asap: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/COUCHDB

Comment: see the update in my answer - Cloudant says it's only a problem with v1.0.2 if you're using an Erlang earlier than R14. Still worth a bug report?